# Here SDK Android Zoom to several markers

Tags: android, here-api

Im currently testing out Here Maps SDK for Android. I have a set of markers and i need to be able to zoom in so they all fit the screen. I currently tried using GeoBoundingBox but you have to insert 2 places at once (the corners). Searched the documentation but didnt find any relevant information. **Is it possible and how can I do it?**

**How I tried to do it**

```
 GeoBoundingBox geoBoundingBox = hereMap.getBoundingBox();
    if (data != null && data.getItemGroups() != null) {
        for (ItemGroup itemGroup: data.getItemsGroups()) {
            ClusterLayer clusterLayer = new ClusterLayer();
            for (Item item : itemGroup.getItems()) {
                if (item != null && item.isLatLngOk()) {
                    GeoCoordinate coordinate = new GeoCoordinate(item .getLat(), item .getLng());
                    clusterLayer.addMarker(new MapMarker(coordinate, image));
                    geoBoundingBox.merge(new GeoBoundingBox(coordinate, coordinate));
                }
            }
            hereMap.addClusterLayer(clusterLayer);
            hereMap.zoomTo(geoBoundingBox, Map.Animation.LINEAR, 0); // This does not work
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please note why question was downvoted. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main issue was that Here SDK merge method returns a new geoBounding box instead of set new values to the old one. So the main change was:

```
geoBoundingBox = geoBoundingBox.merge(new GeoBoundingBox(coordinate, coordinate));
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to merge an initial empty bounding box with a singularity points?

Best is to start with a bounding box consisting of the first two markers and then expand it to fit additional Geocoordinate.

Comment: Please print out the topLeft() and bottomRight() of the bounding box after you add each point? Should let you know what the problem was.

Comment: Thanks, your answer did help. Although the main problem was different